# How do I implement a before_filter callback in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, before-filter

Say I got this singleton object with some public methods and one private method:

```
var QuestionFactory = (function() {

// private method
function google_it_first() { ... }

// public methods
return {
  ask_a_stupid_question:                function() { ... },
  ask_a_relatively_non_stupid_question: function() { ... },
  ask_a_difficult_question:             function() { ... }
}  

})();
```

What I'd like to be able to do is call `google_it_first` method first, when any public method is called. How do I implement it without explicitly calling it inside each public method?

Answer (score 2):

```
function wrapper() {
  return function() {
    google_it_first();
    return arguments[0](arguments.slice(1,arguments.length);
  }
}

ask_a_stupid_question: wrapper(function() { ... })
```

Of the top of my head, I think that would work.

Comment: +1 That was my first thought also, just note that `arguments` unfortunately is not a *real array* object, you need to invoke the `slice` method on the `Array.prototype` object using `call`. E.g: `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);`, also, you might want to use `apply` to invoke the wrapped function and send the arguments separately, e.g. `arguments[0].apply(null, args);`

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand it, but it seems that I'd have to use wrapper function on each of the methods. Which is, in terms of code duplication, is identical to calling google_it_first() inside each of those methods. What's the point then?

Comment: Yes, you would have to do that.  The thing is you can then add as many functions to the wrapper without having to change it for all the methods. I would debate that the mechanism is quite different in terms of duplication as it still separates aspects/concerns.  The point is that that is how javascript works.  Before_filters in rails are implemented in the request system rather than at the method level anyway.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to apply the wrapper function to each method, but you can do that by saying `for (method in methods) rv[method] = wrap(methods[method]);`. That is, in terms of code duplication, not at all identical to calling `google_it_first()` inside of each method.